# É possível desenvolver apps no docker sem hyper-v?

Tags: docker

Crio aplicativos usando HTML, CSS e javascript, e também usando frameworks como ionic. Por um motivo ou outro, sempre tive que manualmente configurar o ambiente de desenvolvimento, o que sempre tomou muito tempo. Até que um dia não teve como procrastinar o aprendizado do docker. Então rodei duas vezes:

- Em uma máquina virtual com O.S. de 32 bits (que não deu certo, pois a
  imagem docker exigia arquitetura de 64 bits)
- No gerenciador de hyper-v do windows 10, em uma máquina que não é minha, mas rodava sistema de 64 bits virtualizado.

O problema central, é que o processador da minha máquina de trabalho não tem esse recurso, mas tenho a impressão de ter lido em algum lugar que o linux não precisa de hyper-v para rodar docker. E instalar um sistema operacional com o propósito errado pode atrasar em muito meus projetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além dos recursos do processador e a arquitetura do seu SO, é preciso conhecer quais as edições do Docker estão disponíveis. A versão do seu sistema também irá influenciar.

**Docker Desktop**: É a forma recomendada para executar o Docker no sistema Windows. Ele se integra melhor ao sistema operacional, possibilitando usar localhost para os binds de rede, sincronização com o sistema de arquivos e gerenciamento automático da VM que executa o Docker.

Ele requer o Hyper-V para ser executado (consequentemente é preciso suporte a virtualização e também o Windows 10 Pro). No futuro será possível rodar no Windows 10 Home quando o Docker Desktop utilizar o WSL 2, porém ainda precisa de virtualização.

**Docker Toolkit**: É um pacote de utilitários parecido com o Docker Desktop, mas é baseado no Virtualbox e não conta com uma integração mais profunda com o sistema operacional. Porém ele pode ser utilizado em sistemas mais antigos, como o Windows 7. Essa opção também requer virtualização.

**Docker no Linux**: Ao utilizar Linux você não precisa ter suporte a virtualização para rodar o Docker. Não tenho certeza se você pode usar um sistema 32-bits com as versões mais recente do Docker.

> É possível desenvolver apps no docker sem hyper-v?

Sem o Hyper-V é possível usar o Docker Toolkit com o Virtualbox no Windows ou com uma máquina virtual com Linux. Ainda sim você precisa de suporte a virtualização.

Verifique se seu processador realmente não tem suporte a virtualização, as vezes essa opção só esta desabilitada na BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta é sim! É possível desenvolver apps no docker sem hyper-v. Essa informação chegou a mim enquanto escrevia essa pergunta, mas resolvi continuar editando para desenvolvedores que passarem por dúvida similar. E tem dois motivos simples: Contêiner e virtualização. E para sistemas linux, isolar processos é uma rotina comum, feita nativamente, sem a necessidade de virtualização. Confusão comum de quem não está totalmente imerso na cultura DevOps, como é meu caso.

Comment: Eu usaria o termo "moda DevOps". Digo isso, pq sou da época que não tinha tanta buzzword, e o cara de TI montava o PC, lia o esquema da placa mãe (que vinha no manual dos Amiga, por exemplo), entendia de eletrônica digital, lia manual, achava material mesmo sem internet, aprendia a programar de verdade e antes de sequer pensar em escrever código, analisava e entendia o problema a ser resolvido (toda equipe), e o software era só manifestação. Hoje eu vejo muitas "sombras" disso, uma tentativa de resgatar o jeito que seria normal de fazer as coisas, mas que foi sendo perdido nas últimas décadas.

Comment: PS: Não desmerecendo nenhum "conceito", claro, só não gosto de ver esse hype todo em cima de termos que surgem e são trocados por outros a cada dois ou três anos, pois me sinto vendo aquela cena que a pessoa parabeniza a outra por ter devolvido uma carteira perdida, como se fosse um "mérito", sendo que devia ser a obrigação de qualquer um (quem faz isso naturalmente não precisa por nome naquilo - a analogia é que quando o cara faz o que já deveria ser o normal, nao precisa de rótulo). Talvez seja consequência da idade, depois de um tempo a gente começa a ver o padrão repetitivo das coisas...

Comment: PS2 (depois vem Wii): Não sei se você tem participado, mas seus pontos já permitem o uso do chat da rede, ótimo para questões mais difusas (em especial, a sala [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), vinculada ao SOpt - durante a semana, em horário de expediente, tem mais movimento, hoje com certeza está "devagar"). - e esse negativo aí no post não foi meu. (EDIT: depois que me toquei que vc já conhece o chat faz tempo, não tinha associado a conta à pessoa :P )

Comment: Sim, para mim também torturante nomenclaturas desnecessárias. Mas ainda preciso delas para me comunicar. Também não gosto disso